# Como disponibilizar um arquivo para dowload inline em html?

Tags: html

Eu queria criar um link pra um dowload no meu HTML, mas não queria guardar este conteúdo em um arquivo separado, mas no próprio html.

Em imagens tem como fazer algo assim

```html
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Será que para links também é possível?

Comment: Você está querendo converter um aquivo para base64 e enviar ele junto ao HTML? Assim ao clicar no link o usuário irá baixar esse arquivo? Se for não aconselho, pois seu HTML irá ficar pesado e irá demorar muito para carregar, sem saber se a pessoa quer ou não baixar o arquivo.

Comment: Isso, mas não estou preocupado com o tamanho do arquivo, ele é pequeno

Comment: Lembrando, pra quem for aplicar as soluções abaixo, de setar um **Content-Security-Policy** adequado, permitindo `data:text/html` (ou outro mime mais adequado) no `default-src`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o MIME-type `data:text/html`

**Renderizar o código HTML quando clicar no link:**

```html
<a href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><body><h1>pt.stackoverflow</h1></body></html>">Clique aqui</a>
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zFnn/)

## HTML5

No HTML5 a tag `<a>`ganhou um recurso de **download**.

**Fazer download do código HTML quando clicar no link:**

```
<a href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><body><h1>pt.stackoverflow</h1></body></html>" download> Clique aqui </a>
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zFnn/1/)

Seria isso o que você quer?

Mais informações sobre DATA URI [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
Sobre o recurso do download na tag `<a>` vi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16194104).

---

**Nota:** Na maioria dos navegadores o `data:` é considerado uma origem separada, então em alguns contextos é necessário setar um [**Content-Security-Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) que permita `data:text/html` (ou outro mime mais adequado) como fonte confiável no `default-src`, para que não haja bloqueio do conteúdo.

Comment: +1 Muito massa essa resposta. :)

Answer (score 3):

Basta fazer isso:

```html
<img alt="Embedded Image" download="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um atributo do **HTML5**: `download="pagina.html"`

Exemplo:

```
<a download="pagina.html" href="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><body><h1>conteúdo/h1></body></html>">Clique aqui</a>
```

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/html/links.html#downloading-resources
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468517/force-download-of-datatext-plain-url/20282249#20282249